Photos notification: "A participant removed photos you added to the shared library" - which ones?
I have a shared Photos library with several participants. Once in a while I get a notification like this: "A participant removed 8 photos you added to the shared library".
When I click the notification (causing it to disappear from every device), it opens Photos to the main library. There's no indication which photos were removed. When I check the "Recently Deleted" album, there are no photos there that were added by me.
How can I find out what photos the notification was referring to, and/or which participant removed them?

I tagged this macOS, please indicate which library on which OS is considered the master for these notifications and testing.

@bmike I don't understand what you're asking. It's an iCloud Shared Photo Library which is accessible from the Photos app on both MacOS and iOS. I received the same notification on both MacOS and iOS devices.
